# How to reduce query time of the sql statement,mysql

Tags: mysql

Here is the sql(mysql):

> Table product and product_sale_app

it will pass in two parameters,appkey is the attribute of table product_sale_app;category  is the attribute  of table product.I need get effect_date,product_id,name from table product and use the  above conditions.

```
SELECT effect_date,
       product_id,
       name
    FROM product
    WHERE product_id IN
        (SELECT product_id
         FROM product_sale_app
         WHERE appkey =88888
           AND product_id IN
             (SELECT product_id
              FROM product
              WHERE category =1 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sub queries, `JOIN` the tables using `product_id` and then put conditions inside the `WHERE` clause.

Try the following:

```
SELECT p.effect_date,
       p.product_id,
       p.name
FROM product AS p 
JOIN product_sale_app AS psa ON psa.product_id = p.product_id 
WHERE p.category = 1 AND psa.appkey = 88888
```

Comment: Thank you , but I wrote the same as you did before, and it cost 700 ms.so I want to optimize this sql.

Comment: @zhuyong share the indexing details on the tables product and product_sale_app

Comment: PRIMARY product_id of product; idx_appkey appkey of product_sale_app

Comment: @zhuyong please index `category` field of product table also, and index `product_id` field of product_sale_app table as well

Comment: I will have a try